# How to convert this array to time series with dot separate

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, time-series

How can i convert this transaction_year column with array data type to timeseries type

input

```
df = pd.read_excel("Real estate valuation data set.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
df
```

output

[image]

it's my code

input

```
df['transaction_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_year'], format='%Y.%m')
df
```

output

[image]

from 2019.1 to January 2019 timeseries

Answer (score 0):

You can convert column to strings by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for prevent wrong parsing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_year':[2000.1, 2000.4]})

df['transaction_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_year'].astype(str), format='%Y.%m')
print(df)
  transaction_year
0       2000-01-01
1       2000-04-01
```